# Checking if there are duplicates in a tables

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have been working on an sql code I found online that said that it check if there duplicates online.

What I want to do is that it checks whether if a value has a duplicate in the table it is inserting then I need to return a booleon in PHP but I am  having a problem in MYSQL code. I have this code I have found online:

```
SELECT schedday,schedtime COUNT(schedday, schedtime) as count
FROM scstock
GROUP BY schedday, schedtime
HAVING COUNT(schedday, schedtime) > 1
```

But I am having this error
[image]

Then I tried to modify it to this which is I wanted to accomplish

```
SELECT schedday,schedtime COUNT(schedday, schedtime) as count
FROM scstock
WHERE schedday = 'M/T' AND schedtime = '7:00-9:00/7:00-9:00'
HAVING count > 1
```

But this appears
[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: try this `SELECT schedday,schedtime, COUNT(schedday, schedtime) as count
FROM scstock
GROUP BY schedday, schedtime
HAVING count > 1`

Comment: I don't think you can (or at the very least should) alias a mysql function, there is also a `,` missing in your select statement.

Comment: @sasikumar it is showing an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' schedtime) as count FROM scstock GROUP BY schedday, schedtime HAVING count > 1 ' at line 1"

Comment: Try this `SELECT schedday,schedtime, COUNT(*) as count FROM scstock GROUP BY schedday, schedtime HAVING count > 1`. If possible make a sql fiddle for better solutions.

Comment: Yeah it worked now, thanks @sasikumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below query for your result

```
SELECT schedday,schedtime, COUNT(*) as count FROM scstock GROUP BY schedday, schedtime HAVING count > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error you should put an "," after schedtime

```
SELECT schedday,schedtime , COUNT(schedday, schedtime) as count
FROM scstock
GROUP BY schedday, schedtime
HAVING count > 1
```

Comment: This is showing an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' schedtime) as count
FROM scstock
GROUP BY schedday, schedtime
HAVING count >' at line 1"